# conditional inner join based on null

Tags: sql

So, I've tried going through existing search results but i still feel stumped.  Hopefully someone can help.

I have 3 tables, A(3 columns), B(2 columns), and C(2 columns), and I need to get values in column C1 based on column from A1.

So, if value in A1 is NULL then 'NONE' and simply join with row in C2 and get value of C1.

But, if value in A1 is NOT NULL then match the value with row in B2, then match value of B1 with C2, which gives us value of C1.

How do I go about achieving such, i understand there is inner and left join but it just wont come out right.

Below is an example data.

```
Table - A

+--------+----+----+
| A1     | A2 | A3 |
+--------+----+----+
| Cake   | 22 | X  |
| (null) | 20 | Y  |
| Butter | 30 | Z  |
+--------+----+----+

Table - B

+-----+--------+
| B1  | B2     |
+-----+--------+
| EAT | Cake   |
| USE | Oil    |
| PRO | Butter |
+-----+--------+

Table - C

+-----+--------+
| C1  | C2     |
+-----+--------+
| 100 | EAT    |
| 200 | USE    |
| 999 | NONE   |
| 300 | PRO    |
+-----+--------+
```

any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Help us help you.  What have you tried so far?  What database are you using?

Comment: using Oracle, i've tried case when column is Null then 'N/A and another case when is NOT NULL then column_name end = B2, but it does not return right results.

Answer (score 2):

Query :

```
SELECT * FROM 
(    SELECT a1,c1 FROM a,b,c 
            WHERE a.a1=b.b2 AND b.b1=c.c2 
     UNION
     SELECT b2,c1 FROM b JOIN c on b1=c2
) X 
UNION 
SELECT a1,c1 FROM a,c WHERE a1 IS NULL AND c2='NONE';
```

I am obtaining **both** a1 and c1 since c1 values may be jumbled and this distinguishes it. If you want c1 values in given order then please do inform although that query might be a little difficult.

Comment: so, final answer would be values from c1 - 100, 999, 300

Comment: I must say, your answer works, but i was not looking to use union.  So, I kept at it and found solution that works for me.  Which is,  select c1 from (select A1 from A)x inner join C on case when x.A1 is null then 'NONE' else (Select B1 from B where B2 = A1) end = C.C2

Answer (score 0):

Found solution that works for me, and Nicole's answer is correct as well.

```
select c1 from (select A1 from A)x 
inner join C on case when x.A1 is null then 'NONE' 
                 else (Select B1 from B where B2 = A1) 
                 end = C.C2
```